# increment value for a joined df and a conditional match in R

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I need to increment a value in a table based off data in another table that matches a condition.

```
Table 1
UID     Tally
111     0
112     0
113     0

Table 2
UID         Code
111         A
112         B
113         B
```

I need to increment tally to 1 when a left join is done and "B" is found.  This is what I have tried

```
Table1$tally <- Table1 %>%
left_join(Table2, by=UID) %>%
if(Code %in% c("A")) {
tally = 1}
```

Throws an interoperable error.

Example data:

```
Table1 <- read.table(text="
UID     Tally
111     0
112     0
113     0
", header=T)

Table2 <- read.table(text="
UID         Code
111         A
112         B
113         B", 
header=T)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the `r` tag to meet the sitewide requirement for Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples we ask that you recreate the data within the code itself, or use `dput()` or use a builtin data set, Also please include an example of the desired resulting table for a question like this, just for clarity's sake.

Comment: you want a count of all the UID's based on the value 'B' in the Code field? So, in the example you have, the Tally field would be 0, 1, 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there, you just need to do it as a `mutate()` explicitly (like a line in an SQL 'select'):

```
Table1 %>% left_join(Table2, by="UID") %>% mutate(Tally = if_else(Code=="B", 1L, Tally))

#  UID Tally Code
#1 111     0    A
#2 112     1    B
#3 113     1    B
```

Comment: Thanks! I did run into this error thought:  Evaluation error: `false` must be type integer, not double.

Comment: @GarrettArcher - just remove the `1L` and replace it with `1` . `Tally` is in integer in the example data here but yours is obviously a numeric. `dplyr` is strict about types so you can't put a numeric and integer together.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if your Table2 data has multiple instances of UIDs (hence your tally for a single UID could exceed 1), you should be using this method to count the Bs of each UID instead of a `left_join`

```
Table1 <- Table2 %>% group_by(UID) %>%
  summarise(tally = sum(Code == 'B'))
```